# How to display base price in virtue mart2?

Tags: joomla2.5, virtuemart

I am using Joomla 2.5.8 and virtue mart version 2.0.14.I want to display Base price and Final sale price in fronted,but it displays only sales price and not showing the base price.when i login using administrator account it displays both prices but without login it displays only sales price.How can i solve this issue please help me,i am new in virtue mart and one more is i want to show base price with strikeout.

Answer (score 1):

In the admin side of virtuemart there is a configuration link.There you can see 'PRICE '
tab.There you can check the prices you want show in the front end. so check the base price show option. thats it.

(This will be the configuration URL     yoursitename/administrator/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=config)

Comment: Thank You sir,I already checked the Base price and Final sales price check boxes but it displays only the sales price.